# How to show only reviews of current logged in user in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I need a little help regarding OpenCart

I want to show reviews only to logged In customers *[I have succeeded in that]*

But now I want to show review only to user who have wrote it.

**Example:**

If User A logged in and wrote a Review Only User A will see it not any other users

If User B logged in and wrote a Review Only user B will see his review, not user A or any other logged in user.

Why I Want This:

I want because if user comes back after few days or months he can see his review, I don't want to show all reviews to all users only to user who have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model `ModelCatalogReview` there are 2 functions you need to change: `getReviewsByProductId` and `getTotalReviewsByProductId`.

`getReviewsByProductId`:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT r.review_id, r.author, r.rating, r.text, p.product_id, pd.name, p.price, p.image, r.date_added FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (r.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p.status = '1' AND r.status = '1' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND r.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' ORDER BY r.date_added DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
```

(notice `AND r.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'`)

`getTotalReviewsByProductId`:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (r.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p.status = '1' AND r.status = '1' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND r.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
```

(notice `AND r.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'`)

This also lists the comments to logged in user only, because there are no comments with the `customer_id = '0'`.

**Later Edit:**
This applies to `Opencart 1.5.5.1`. If you are using a different version, you might need to change the code a little.

Comment: @Hassaan Since this is the correct answer you should consider accepting it (clicking on the *tick* icon on the left to this answer).